# Best approach of testing ravendb database queries speed

Tags: ravendb, performance-testing

I've searched the internet for a while but am not able to find any examples how to test RavenDb query speed.

What I'm trying to archive is to compare two session.query and find out witch of those two has the best performance speed. How can I do that? //Thanks

EDIT:

I'm building a mvc Notes-app were a user can create an account and save notes. Lets say I have these these two classes:

```
public class SingleNote : ContentPage
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Is it best to put a List of the users singleNotes in the LoginViewodel and store all the user notes there or should I put a property in the the SingleNote-ravenDocument that refers to the user.

What I'm then trying to achieve is to test these to different types of queries and see which of them gets the best performance / speed.

SO TO THE RELEVANT QUESTIOIN: can I do some testing of that, and compare these two queries and see witch of them gets best performance speed:

Case 1: where I have put the prop string UserThatOwnsTheDoc in SingleNote-class
The risk here I have to query all my documents In the collection "SingleNotes". Which results in searching though many documents. Can that be an issue?

```
var listOfSpecificUsersDocuments =
        RavenSession.Query<SingleNote>()
                .Where(o => o.UserThatOwnsTheDoc == User.Identity.Name)
                .ToList();`
```

Case 2: where I have put the prop `List<SingleNote> SingleNotes` in the LoginViewModel

In this case I store every note in UserDocument. The risk here is that the documentsize can grow very large if the list of "SingleNotes". Can that be an issue?

```
var userDocumentWitchIncludesAListOfSingleNotes = RavenSession.Load<LoginViewModel>("UserName/1");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say what you are interested in is not in fact performance testing, but actually **stress testing**. Suppose you complete your performance analysis and find one way is "faster" does "faster" actually mean anything? It sure doesn't mean anything if your "faster" solution breaks under load.

The type of testing you are looking to do is **very nontrivial** and will require real effort to achieve. Instead of looking at performance in isolation you need to look at the overall experience to the user. You need to plan a scenario (or series of scenarios that could run concurrently) that emulates the behavior of the system in a real world scenario.

Taking Twitter, a "simple" stress test might involve 1000 users register, 800 login, 400 post 100 tweets, 200 post 1000 tweets, and all 1000 search for users to follow linking to 100 other users. Do all of this concurrently. Monitor the performance of the various parts of the system, is one action becoming a detriment to the others? When is the fracturing point of the system?

So circling back to your question, the solution here is build both possible solutions. Then use a standard load tester against the MVC end of the application. This will show you how many concurrent users you can support with good experience, slowed down experience, and eventually lights out. For legitimate testing make sure your application is deployed to a real server and is running IIS with a comparable quality production server. (aka don't use your Windows 8, use Windows Server 2012. IIS is degraded on consumer editions to prevent it from being used as a server)

Some simple advice to relearning object modeling when in a document world instead a relational world. You are seeking to model transaction boundaries. If X changes, Y needs to change too? Those should likely be in the same document.  `LoginViewModel` does this need to have a `List<Note>`, or rephrased when a user logs in do i need at every single moment the list of all associated notes? If the answer is yes, I need them at all times, that is a clear sign it belongs in the same document. If the answer is "it depends" or "sometimes" that implies it does not belong in the same document. If what you're trying to do feels "hard" that's a pretty clear sign you have a bad document model. Well modeled nonrelational systems can commonly respond to any individual request with a single `Load<T>` statement or single `Query<T>`. If you need multiple loads that you cannot solve with a single `LoadStartingWith<T>` there is likely something wrong, similar if you multiple queries.